# python loop again if certain value?

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to make a program that plays "Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock" with the user.  I've gotten most of it working, but one issue I'm having is that if the game comes to a tie, I'd like that outcome to be disregarded, and the loop to repeat.  In another way of putting it, I want there to be three win/lose outcomes.  Additionally, to totally mess with what I just said, I'd like it if when the user wins twice in a row or the program wins twice in a row, it exits the loop entirely.

For the first issue, I tried using continue, but that didn't work at all.  I've been through several rock paper scissors questions on this site, but I didn't see any answers that would apply here.  The first issue has the priority; the second is just the cherry on top.

Here is my code (It's a little long, I'm very sorry):

```
import random
Rock = "Rock"
Paper = "Paper"
Scissors = "Scissors"
Lizard = "Lizard"
Spock = "Spock"
Words = (Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock)


def The_Game (x):
    for i in range(3):
        y = random.choice(Words)
        x = input("Choose your weapon! Rock, paper, scissors, lizard, or spock?")
        if x == y:
            print(y)
            print("Tie. Try again!")
        else:
            if x == Rock:
                if y == Paper:
                    print(y)
                    print("Paper covers Rock.  You lost this round!")
                elif (y == Spock):
                    print(y)
                    print("Spock vaporizes Rock. You lost this round!")
                elif (y == Lizard):
                    print(y)
                    print("Rock crushes Lizard. You won this round!")
                else:
                    print(y)
                    print("As always, Rock crushes Scissors.  You won this round!")
            elif (x == Paper):
                if y == Scissors:
                    print(y)
                    print("Scissors cut Paper.  You lost this round!")
                elif (y == Lizard):
                    print(y)
                    print("Lizard eats paper.  You lost this round!")
                elif (y == Rock):
                    print(y)
                    print("Paper covers Rock.  You won this round!")
                else:
                    print(y)
                    print("Paper disproves Spock.  You won this round!")
            elif (x == Scissors):
                if y == Rock:
                    print(y)
                    print("As always, Rock crushes Scissors.  You lost this round!")
                elif (y == Spock):
                    print(y)
                    print("Spock melts scissors.  You lost this round!")
                elif (y == Paper):
                    print(y)
                    print("Scissors cut Paper.  You won this round!")
                else:
                    print(y)
                    print("Scissors decapitate Lizard.  You won this round!")
            elif (x == Lizard):
                if y == Rock:
                    print(y)
                    print("Rock crushes Lizard. You lost this round!")
                elif (y == Scissors):
                    print(y)
                    print("Scissors decapitate Lizard.  You lost this round!")
                elif (y == Paper):
                    print(y)
                    print("Lizard eats Paper.  You won this round!")
                elif (y == Spock):
                    print(y)
                    print("Lizard poisons Spock.  You won this round!")
            else:
                if y == Paper:
                    print(y)
                    print("Paper disproves Spock.  You lost this round!")
                elif (y == Lizard):
                    print(y)
                    print("Lizard poisons Spock.  You lost this round!")
                elif (y == Scissors):
                    print(y)
                    print("Spock melts scissors.  You won this round!")
                else:
                    print(y)
                    print("Spock vaporizes Rock. You won this round!")


x = ("Let's play Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock!  Best 2 of three!")
print(x)
The_Game(x)

Yes = "Yes"
No = "No"
p = input("Play again? (Yes or No)  ")
    if p == Yes:
        The_Game(x)
    else:
        print("Thanks for playing!")
```

If anyone could assist, that would be wonderful! I'm just a beginner in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, let's change your code slightly first. Instead of having `TheGame()` play 3 times, let's just have it play once.

Then, once we've done that, we can make each call to `TheGame()` have a useful return value.  One useful value to get back would be if the user won. One way of presenting this would be to do `return True` if the player wins, and `return False` otherwise.

For example:

```
if x == Rock and y == Paper:
    print(y)
    print("Paper covers Rock.  You lost this round!")
    return False
```

Then, your main loop could become something like this:

```
print("Let's play Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock!  Best 2 of three!")

win_count = 0
loss_count = 0
while win_count < 2 and loss_count < 2:
    if The_Game(x) == True:
        win_count = win_count + 1
    else:
        loss_count = loss_count + 1

if win_count == 2:
    print("You won the set!")
else:
    print("You lost the set!")
```

One note: You may want to check that the user's input is within the range you desire. You could check this with the conditional: `if x not in Words:`

Comment: He is including the both-choose-the-same case in the `if x == y:` block.

Comment: Thanks very much! Could you assist with the part about restarting the function if there's a tie?